# js string replace does not work

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to replace ',",\ characters with blank.

I use the following code

```
jQuery.get('/path to file/file.txt',function(data){
  data = data.replace(/\'\"\\/g," ");
  alert(data);
})
```

but nothing replaced.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression would replace the 3 character sequence `'"\` with a space, not the individual chars `\`,  `'` and `"`.  Enclose them in a character class  `[]` (and there's no need to escape with `\` except for the `\`).

```
data = data.replace(/['"\\]/g," ");

// Example:
var str = "This string has internal \" double \\ quotes \\ and 'some single ones' and a couple of backslashes";
str = str.replace(/['"\\]/g," ");
// Output: all quotes replaced with spaces:
// "This string has internal   double   quotes   and  some single ones  and a couple of backslashes"
```

Comment: Except for the slash, which does need to be escaped (as OP had in the question, `\\ `)

Answer (score 1):

you are wrong. there is nothing to replace.
regex does not open any file. all it does is replacing the char combination `'"` with whitespace.

what you search for is `['"]` instead of  `\'\"`